# Espejo Sql Server Ip Publica

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net

Estimados tengo una aplicación winform vb.net que utiliza sql server algunos clientes utilizan ip publica y puerto para conectarse al motor.Como cubrir la replicacion o un modo espejo del motor por si falla la conexión.La idea es tener 2 servidores Vps en distintos proveedores y que ambos tengan la información de forma paralela.Gracias

Answer (score 0):

*SQL Server* tiene la característica de ***Mirroring***. Solo tienes que dar clic derecho en la base de datos que quieres reflejar, seleccionar **Propiedades** y aparece una ventana con opciones, en la parte superior derecha, un botón para configurar la seguridad, el cual te abre un asistente que te guía paso a paso.

[image: SQL Server Mirroring]

Se recomienda crear otra instancia como *Witness Server* para poder hacer el ***Failover*** automático, pero depende mucho de cómo vayas a trabajar tu solución de *VB.NET*.